# How to change gtk to cocona, when SWT load native library?

Tags: java, macos, swt, jface

I do not know why SWT load libswt-gtk-4332.jnilib. I used mac os and built SWT/Jface Project with Runnable Jar. I run Runnable Jar but I failed. Outputed the error log.

I executed it in mac:

```
java -jar -verbose threed-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
no swt-gtk-4332 in java.library.path: [/Users/admin/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions, /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions, /usr/lib/java, .]
no swt-gtk in java.library.path: [/Users/admin/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions, /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions, /usr/lib/java, .]
Can't load library: /var/root/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4332.jnilib
Can't load library: /var/root/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-gtk.jnilib

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.isValidSubclass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.checkSubclass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.createShell(Window.java:487)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
at PlayerTableTree.run(Application.kt:20)
at ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:303)
at ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt)
```

Comment: SWT jars are specific to the operating system. It looks like to are trying to use the Linux jar on macOS. You must use the correct SWT jar for the OS.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but SWT dependency is 'group: "org.eclipse.swt", name:"org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64", version:"4.3"' (on gradle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I used Jzy3d Library. Jzy3d SWT injected the gtk swt...
Thx for @greg-44, your comment was hint.